# How to convert JSON to string on UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

Hi I am receiving the JSON in the below format how can i show it on the UI..in the custom LWC table.

```
    evEventsList":[
              {
                 "description":"Baby Brand Specific - Spend $600 Get $150",
                 "durationType":"FIXED",
                 "earnedAmount":150,
                 "earnedValueEventType":"spendXGetY",
                 "eventEndDate":{
                    "time":"12/12/2022 03:00:00"
                 },
                 "eventId":"DC11400001",
                 "eventStartDate":{
                    "time":"10/10/2020 23:00:00"
                 },
                 "relativePeriod":0,
                 "spentAmount":600
              }
 ]
```

I am storing this data properly in the variable.

not able to show the start date and end date in custom table.

Below is my HTML.

```
<tbody>
    <template for:each={troubleshootData} for:item="eachcol" for:index="Index">
        <tr  key={eachcol.eventId} data-row={eachcol}>
            <td key={eachcol.eventId} class="slds-cell-wrap tabcol">
                <span>{eachcol.eventId}</span>
            </td>
            <td key={eachcol.eventId} class="slds-cell-wrap tabcol">
                <span>{eachcol.eventStartDate}</span>
            </td>
            <td key={eachcol.eventId} class="slds-cell-wrap tabcol">
                <span>{eachcol.eventEndDate}</span>
            </td>
            <td key={eachcol.eventId} class="slds-cell-wrap tabcol">
                <span>{eachcol.earnedAmount}</span>
            </td>
            <td key={eachcol.eventId} class="slds-cell-wrap tabcol">
                <span>{eachcol.description}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

kinldy help me to show the start date and end date on the UI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the properties as in your object:

```
<span>{eachcol.eventStartDate.time}</span>
```